# ALL Prime Numbers Within 2 Columns of Number Pyramid - Proof?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

I was arranging numbers putting them in different orders when I happened to build a pyramid and noticed that two columns of the pyramid seemed to contain all of the prime numbers. Not just some of them, but all of the first hundred primes at least.

Considering how rare I thought that might be, I'm bringing it here for consideration.

I began with the numbers 5, 6, 7 at top. Then going diagonal to the left for 5, I did 5*2, then 5*3, etc as the left side of the triangle. On the right I did 7*1, then 7*2, etc going down the right side of the triangle.

This means the top row is 5, 6, 7. The next row is 10, 11, 12, 13, 14. The next is 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21... and so on.
[image]
If you look at the columns under 5 and 7 they contain ALL of the prime numbers.

Is there a way to create a proof that all prime numbers do NOT exist in these two columns?

Comment: Those columns look like they contain all odd numbers that are not divisible by $3$.

Comment: The left hand consists of those numbers of the form $6n-1$.  The right consists of all numbers of the form $6n+1$.  Every prime $>3$ is of one of those types.

Comment: Another observation I've found is that non-prime numbers from the f(x) = (6n+-1) are always a factor of primes from the (6n-1)*(6n+1) , and never exist as a factor of primes from only one side (e.g. (6a-1)*(6b-1)),

Comment: One more observation is that non-prime numbers from the f(n)=(6n+1) are always a factor from within the same column, e.g. 5*5, or 5*11, or 7*7, or 7*13, etc.

Comment: You are missing out some primes in other columns. For example the column headed by 25, that has 31, 37, 43... They are of the form 6n+1. But also 30+{1,7,13} I recommend you some group theory to see that they sit nicely in modular unit group of the form 2*3*5... For example: all elements of the unit group of 210 below 121=11*11 are primes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The column under $5$ consists of all numbers of the form $6n-1$, and the column under $7$ consists of all numbers of the form $6n+1$.  All primes $> 3$ are of one of these forms.

Comment: similarly all the columns headed by 25,35,49,55,77,65,91,85,119,95,133,115,161 will together in ordered groupings of 2 hold all primes greayer than them ...